# Android: set textview rtl

Tags: java, android, textview, right-to-left, gravity

I`m trying to set the gravity of textview to right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:textDirection="anyRtl"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#000000">
</TextView>
```

In all the phones I tested it`s ok exept GT-S5830 (2.3.4), in the GT only if I remove the android:gravity="right" it set to right.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this android:layout_gravity="right"

Comment: remove android:textDirection="anyRtl" and try android:gravity="right"

Comment: Already tried all the combinations... nothing works in all phones

Answer (score 0):

Use from this :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```